# Weird non-lisp errors with capturing labels with a lambda and `reduce`

Tags: lambda, crash, closures, common-lisp, allegro-cl

I stumbled across a very weird bug (?) while I was developing an application in Allegro Common Lisp, v9.0 for Windows. I do not get the regular lisp errors, instead I get system errors encapsulated in a lisp condition. I managed to create a simple test-case to reproduce the error (it's very silly):

```
(defun lambda-producer ()
  (labels ((producer-label (x y)
                           (if (> x y) (- x y) (- y x)))
           (producer-label2 (x y)
                            (max (producer-label x 2) (producer-label y 3))))
  (lambda (x)
    (reduce (lambda (a b) (producer-label2 a b)) x))))

;; Get errors when calling:
(funcall (lambda-producer) (list 2 1 5 12))
```

I get a Stack overflow error for this test case every time I try it.

In my original code I got a plethora of errors, mostly segmentation faults, once a 'can not take `car` of <..> because it is not listp' and once Allegro crashed.

When running the same snippet (or my original code) in CLisp, everything runs fine and the REPL gives an answer.

**My question:** Am I doing something wrong or illegal here, or is there a bug in Allegro CL? If so, can we determine what that bug is and what to do about it?

---

Some experimentation seems to indicate that the `reduce` and double labels are essential in reproducing the error; replacing `reduce` with a `funcall` or if there is only one label does not give an error.

Comment: Hard to say. Looks like it is implementation specific. I would propose to ask the Franz support about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a compiler bug.  Please contact Franz.

```
CG-USER(8): (disassemble (lambda-producer))
;; disassembly of #<Closure Template Function (:INTERNAL LAMBDA-PRODUCER 0)>
;; formals: X
;; closure vectors:
;;      0: #<Closure (LABELS LAMBDA-PRODUCER PRODUCER-LABEL2) @ #xdfdda7a>
;;      1: #<Function (LABELS LAMBDA-PRODUCER PRODUCER-LABEL)>
;; constant vector:
0: #<Closure Template Function (:INTERNAL (:INTERNAL LAMBDA-PRODUCER 0) 0)>
1: REDUCE

;; code start: #x21869018:
   0: 55          pushl ebp
   1: 89 e5     movl    ebp,esp
   3: 83 ec 38  subl    esp,$56
   6: 89 75 fc  movl    [ebp-4],esi
   9: 89 5d e4  movl    [ebp-28],ebx
  12: 39 63 1a  cmpl    [ebx+26],esp
  15: 76 03     jbe 20
  17: ff 57 43  call    *[edi+67]      ; SYS::TRAP-STACK-OVFL
  20: 83 f9 01  cmpl    ecx,$1
  23: 74 03     jz  28
  25: ff 57 8b  call    *[edi-117]    ; SYS::TRAP-WNAERR
  28: 8b 5d 00  movl    ebx,[ebp+0]
  31: 8b 5b ec  movl    ebx,[ebx-20]
  34: 8b 5b fa  movl    ebx,[ebx-6]
  37: 80 7f cb 00 cmpb  [edi-53],$0        ; SYS::C_INTERRUPT-PENDING
  41: 74 03     jz  46
  43: ff 57 87  call    *[edi-121]    ; SYS::TRAP-SIGNAL-HIT
  46: 8b 56 12  movl    edx,[esi+18] ; #<Closure Template Function (:INTERNAL (:INTERNAL LAMBDA-PRODUCER 0) 0)>
  49: ff b7 43 fe pushl [edi-445] ; SYS::CLOSURE-HEADER
      ff ff 
  55: 8f 45 d0  popl    [ebp-48]
  58: ff b7 47 fe pushl [edi-441] ; SYS::CLOSURE-ADDRESS
      ff ff 
  64: 8f 45 d4  popl    [ebp-44]
  67: 89 55 d8  movl    [ebp-40],edx
  70: 89 5d dc  movl    [ebp-36],ebx
  73: 8d 5d e2  leal    ebx,[ebp-30]
  76: 89 c2     movl    edx,eax
  78: 89 d8     movl    eax,ebx
  80: 8b 5e 16  movl    ebx,[esi+22] ; REDUCE
  83: ff 57 27  call    *[edi+39]      ; SYS::TRAMP-TWO
  86: 89 7d f0  movl    [ebp-16],edi
  89: c9          leave
  90: 8b 75 fc  movl    esi,[ebp-4]
  93: c3          ret

;; disassembly of #<Closure Template Function (:INTERNAL (:INTERNAL LAMBDA-PRODUCER 0) 0)>
;; formals: A B

;; code start: #x2186ccc0:
   0: 55          pushl ebp
   1: 89 e5     movl    ebp,esp
   3: 83 ec 30  subl    esp,$48
   6: 89 75 fc  movl    [ebp-4],esi
   9: 89 5d e4  movl    [ebp-28],ebx
  12: 39 63 1a  cmpl    [ebx+26],esp
  15: 76 03     jbe 20
  17: ff 57 43  call    *[edi+67]      ; SYS::TRAP-STACK-OVFL
  20: 83 f9 02  cmpl    ecx,$2
  23: 74 03     jz  28
  25: ff 57 8b  call    *[edi-117]    ; SYS::TRAP-WNAERR
  28: 8b 5d 00  movl    ebx,[ebp+0]
  31: 8b 5b ec  movl    ebx,[ebx-20]
  34: 8b 5b fa  movl    ebx,[ebx-6]
  37: 80 7f cb 00 cmpb  [edi-53],$0        ; SYS::C_INTERRUPT-PENDING
  41: 74 03     jz  46
  43: ff 57 87  call    *[edi-121]    ; SYS::TRAP-SIGNAL-HIT
  46: ff 73 f6  pushl   [ebx-10]
  49: 8f 45 dc  popl    [ebp-36]        ; EXCL::|local-0|
  52: 8b 75 dc  movl    esi,[ebp-36] ; EXCL::|local-0|
  55: 89 fb     movl    ebx,edi
  57: b9 02 00 00 movl  ecx,$2
      00 
  62: ff 57 23  call    *[edi+35]      ; SYS::FUNCALL-TRAMP
  65: 89 7d f0  movl    [ebp-16],edi
  68: c9          leave
  69: 8b 75 fc  movl    esi,[ebp-4]
  72: c3          ret
  73: 90          nop
```

At 49 and 52 of the second closure template, you can see that it's feeding itself to `sys::funcall-tramp`<sup>1</sup> with 2 arguments<sup>2</sup>.

---

1. `sys::funcall-tramp` is an internal that I think might perform or otherwise allow tail calls.
2. According to `ecx` at 57, since `ecx` is what seems to be used to check if the internal `sys::trap-wnaerr` is called;  I suppose `wna` stands for **w**rong **n**umber of **a**rguments.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've sent in a bug report to Franz, referencing this question and answer.